# On a usage of generic freeness lemma (Vakil's FOAG)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

Here is an exercise from Vakil's FOAG.

> 7.4.L.Exercise. Suppose $X \to Y$ is a finite type morphism of Noetherian schemes, and $Y$ is irrreducible. Show that there is a dense opens subset $U$ of $Y$ such that the image of $\pi$ either contains $U$ or does not meet $U$. (Hint: suppose $\pi: \operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} B$ is such a morphism. Then by the Generic Freeness lemma 7.4.4, there is a nonzero $f \in B$ such that $A_f$ is a free $B_f$-module. **It must have zero rank or positive rank. In the first case, show that the image of $\pi$ does not meet $D(f) \subset \operatorname{Spec} B$. In the second case, show that the image of $\pi$ contains $D(f)$.**

I can't figure out how the hint works. How could we derive the information about $\pi$ from the rank of $B_f$-module $A_f$? Any help are welcome, thanks.

Comment: A formatting tip: \operatorname{Spec} produces the correct formatting for $\operatorname{Spec}$. I have upgraded your post with this - please keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: The rank itself is unimportant. What is important is whether it is zero or not. I hope the case when rank is zero (which means $A_{fg}=0$ for some non-zero $g\in B$) is clear. In the other case, show that for any maximal ideal $M$ of $B_f$, $MA_f\neq A_f$ and thus there is some maximal ideal of $A_f$ contracting to $M$, showing the map on specs is onto.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for your hint. But the case when ranks is positive is still not clear to me.  Why $MA_f\neq A_f$ implies there is some maximal ideal of $A_f$ contracting to $M$? And why the map on maxspecs being onto implies the map on specs is onto? Could you elaborate more? Thanks!

Comment: $MA_f\neq A_f$ means $MA_f$ is a proper ideal in $A_f$ and every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal, say $N$. Then the contraction of $N$ clearly contains $M$ and not equal to $B_f$ and since $M$ is maximal, the contraction must be $M$.